Which permission is not too open but not too obscured?
Let me explain you the problem:
We need a rsfile.key.
mkdir keys
openssl rand -base64 768 > rsfile.key

rskey.file permissions has to be not too open, if it is too open, MongoDB will not launch. We have to move the rskey.file to the Docker, so Docker have to access rskey.file.
Set chmod 600 first.
sudo chmod 600 ./keys/

This didnt work. MongoDB refuses to work because permission are too open. Maybe because of ownership? MongoDB  uses 999 commonly in Docker containers.
sudo chown 999:999 ./keys/rsfile.key 

Then, MongoDB can access the file but Docker cannot move the file
to container due to more obscure permissions. If we dont chown 999:999, MongoDB cannot access the file but Docker can move the file to container.
If we set ownership for the folder instead of the file and let Docker move the folder to container,
sudo chmod 0444 ./keys/

This didnt work again. MongoDB inside docker cant read a file inside a read-only folder.
#!/bin/bash

mkdir keys
openssl rand -base64 768 > rsfile.key
sudo cp rsfile.key ./keys/rsfile.key
sudo chmod 0444 ./keys/
sudo chown 999:999 ./keys/rsfile.key
# Start MongoDB service
docker-compose up -d

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb 
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./container-data/mongo/db:/data/db
      - ./keys/:/etc/mongodb/pki/

What am I supposed to do here?

The directory needs to be accessible:
chmod 700 keys

That will allow the key file to be visible inside the container. Then you need to restrict the permissions of the file itself:
chmod 600 keys/rsfile.key

Note that Docker doesn’t move or copy files, it makes them available in the container by mounting the containing volume.
